# Android AdView leaking, probably due to some internal background thread

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, admob

I display an AdMob ad banner within a window created by a fragment. This works, but I'm getting strange leaking problems I don't understand yet. When I open and close the app a lot of times, the ad fragment is properly destroyed every time, but the MainActivity which controls this fragment is leaking:

[image: Leak]

The guilty one is this line in code:

```
adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID_MOTO_G).addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID_ZTE).build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

(You can see below that I already tried to nullify the adRequest, but no result.) Anyway, when I comment these two lines, the leaks don't occur. I tested it twice, because it was hard to believe that this invocation leaks, but it does. Here is the fragment code. As you can see, I even nullify everything that is possible in `onDestroy()`. I can assure that `onDestroy()` is called. `loadAd` starty any background thread. I guess that has to do with that problem.

```
public class SnippetFragment extends Fragment
{
    private AdView mAdView;
    private OnAdFinishedLoadingListener onAdFinishedLoadingListener;
    private Context context;
    private AdRequest adRequest;

    private final String DEVICE_ID_ZTE = "1CA20334345BB1479C43692AFA576456487A48";
    private final String DEVICE_ID_MOTO_G = "131465469A7BE11543543065404B168908CB13C8D1";

    public SnippetFragment(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

        mAdView = (AdView)getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded()
            {
                super.onAdLoaded();

                if (context != null)
                {
                    onAdFinishedLoadingListener = (OnAdFinishedLoadingListener)context;
                    onAdFinishedLoadingListener.onAdLoaded();
                }
            }
        });

        //THIS SOMEHOW LEAKS!
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID_MOTO_G).addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID_ZTE).build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_snippet, container, false);
    }

    /** Called when leaving the activity */
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        if (mAdView != null)
        {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called when returning to the activity */
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null)
        {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        adRequest = null;

        if (mAdView != null)
        {
            mAdView.setAdListener(null);
            mAdView.destroy();
            mAdView = null;
        }

        context = null;

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably not related to the leak but, the `Contractor` of the `Fragment` must be without parameters, the framework, won't call your contractor when fragment is being restored, you can use `getActivitiy()` or `mAddView.getContext()` to get the context

Comment: I see, but it didn't help.

Comment: How do you introduce the leak? Screen rotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fortunately found the solution. You have to manually kick the AdView out of the surrounding layout, before the fragment gets destroyed. No leak anymore after I launched and closed the app about 20 times. Here is the updated fragment:

```
public class SnippetFragment extends Fragment
{
    private AdView adView;
    private OnAdFinishedLoadingListener onAdFinishedLoadingListener;
    private Context context;
    private LatLng routeDestination;
    private AdRequest adRequest;
    private LinearLayout snippetContent;

    private final String DEVICE_ID_ZTE = "2353496z35752t3524267854";
    private final String DEVICE_ID_MOTO_G = "4568735862378523675427897";

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

        snippetContent = (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.snippet_content);
        adView = (AdView)getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded()
            {
                super.onAdLoaded();

                if (context != null)
                {
                    onAdFinishedLoadingListener = (OnAdFinishedLoadingListener)getActivity();
                    onAdFinishedLoadingListener.onAdLoaded();
                }
            }
        });

        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID_MOTO_G).addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID_ZTE).build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_snippet, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        if (adView != null)
        {
            adView.pause();
        }

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if (adView != null)
        {
            adView.resume();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        destroyAdView();

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void destroyAdView()
    {
        if (adView != null)
        {
            adRequest = null;
            adView.removeAllViews();
            adView.setAdListener(null);
            adView.destroy();
            snippetContent.removeView(adView);

            adView = null;
            snippetContent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but unfortunately mine still leaks even after this fix.

Comment: @eliasbagley Then you have somewhere a reference to the fragment or you don't destroy the fragment at all?

Comment: The fragment's onDestroy() method is getting called

Comment: I add the AdView programmatically and remove it from the parent view in the onStop() method of my fragment, as here it's mentioned:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/DnICRC67ASI
And I use the the application context to create the instance of AdView

Comment: why do you do `adView = null;` in `onDestroy`? It's so useless!

Comment: @user25 Why is it useless to tell GC to remove it?

Comment: @Bevor no one does it, it's not C++. And when `onDestroy` is called your process is likely to be killed and removed from memory anyway (if you don't have other activities or services started)

Comment: @user25 It does not matter if it's not C++. When you assign null, you release the reference and GC can clean the object. And as you can see in this example, there was at least one leak due to non released references. So please let's stop discussing about non-problems.

Comment: @GC can handle it itself, there is no book which teaches to set null for all your variables when you don't need those references. And again after `onDestroy` all your objects will die anyway. You call `adView.destroy();` in `onDestroy` and that's enough, setting `null` is useless

Comment: The solution is very old but still it works in todays date