# Admob bad performance on android

Tags: android, performance, admob

Good day, I would like to set banner admob, but the performance is not good it`s takes approximately 5-60sec to load the banner, how to increase this performance ?

This is code from layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

This snippet from onCreate() main activity

```
 AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
          .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
          .addTestDevice("F78E6B09D76CF8E163F9CA18EE11A305")
          .build();
 mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

This is very simple copy-paste from google, but It seems very slow.

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or on emulator?

Comment: I'm using real device Huawei Ascend P6, and an emulator, but on emulator the banner doesn`t loaded at all.

Comment: Maybe it could be that there are some background threads hanging caused by testing. I had another strange issue once, but I solved it. There you can see my implementation which is quite fast: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727483/android-adview-leaking-probably-due-to-some-internal-background-thread